# How to link these database tables together when inserting

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to build a checklist/signoff system. Basically, I've got a form that the user fills out, see below. The user is automatically put there based on who is logged in.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VTKR.jpg

Each Checklist is attached to a specific Job number. So say a manager wants to look at Job 1000, he'll click it, navigate to "Checklists" and he'll see the checklist below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6BTn.jpg

Now, I have an option to select different revisions of a checklist for a job so that managers can look at different revisions.

I'm just not sure on how to string everything together.

I have 2 tables so far.

checklist_component_stock

[image: Imgur]

and checklist_revision

[image: Imgur]

I'm not sure how to link everything correctly in the tables so when Rev1 gets pulled up say for Job 1000, it shows the correct rows that have been created for that specific job and revision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I'm understanding your question correctly, Each time a checklist is updated, I'm guessing that you're currently updating the existing `checklist_component_stock` record, and inserting the new revision information into the `checklist_revision` table..?

If so, then you need to add a `revision` field into your `checklist_component_stock` table, and make this part of the foreign key to the `checklist_revision` table.

Then, when a checklist is changed, **insert** a new record into `checklist_component_stock` with the new revision number, as well as inserting your new revision information into the `checklist_revision` table.

Then, when you pull back a specific revision, you'll do something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM checklist_component_stock a
INNER JOIN checklist_revision b ON a.job_num = b.job_num
                                AND a.revision = b.revision
WHERE a.job_num = xxx
AND a.revision = yyy
```

Comment: Okay I did that and its pulling the correct information when I click a revision (so far I have 3 dummy revisions). I'm struggling a bit with the insert statement, I'm not sure how to link the posts to a revision so when I submit it submits the revision information and the checklists under it are linked to that specific revision, should I create a new question and link you so you can see my html as well ?

Comment: Scratch my above comment, this finally made sense to me. I think I was complicating it a bit too much. Thanks